# Prism Parent TabControl Child Regions

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, tabcontrol

Trying to create a `TabControl` Region inside another Region. The `TabControl` has a set number of `Views` that will be added to it, with their own respective `ViewModels`.

But either the `View` doesn't show up, the `tabitem` doesn't show up with only one `View` displayed instead, or I get the following error:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'This RegionManager does not contain a Region with the name 'ParentTabRegion'. (Parameter 'regionName')'
```

MainMenuView:

```
<Grid>
    <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentRegion" />
</Grid>
```

MainMenuViewModel:

```
public class MainMenuViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManger;

    public MainMenuViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        _regionManger = regionManager;

        _regionManger.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", "ParentView");

    }
}
```

ParentView:

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ParentTabRegion" />
</Grid>
```

ParentViewModel:

```
public class ParentViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManger;

    private Child1View _tab1 = new Child1View();
    private Child1View Tab1
    {
        get { return _tab1; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _tab1, value); }
    }
    private Child2View _tab2 = new Child2View();
    private Child2View Tab2
    {
        get { return _tab2; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _tab2, value); }
    }

    public ParentViewModel(IRegionManager regionManger)
    {
        _regionManger = regionManger;

        // Gives 'This RegionManager does not contain a Region with the name 'GeneralDataTabRegion'. (Parameter 'regionName')' error
        _regionManger.AddToRegion("ParentTabRegion", typeof(Child1View));
        _regionManger.AddToRegion("ParentTabRegion", typeof(Child2View));

        //I've also tried the following
        
        // Same error as above
        // _regionManger.Regions["ParentTabRegion"].Add(typeof(Tab1View));
        // _regionManger.Regions["ParentTabRegion"].Add(typeof(Tab2View));

        // Same error as above
        // _regionManger.AddToRegion("ParentTabRegion", Tab1);
        // _regionManger.AddToRegion("ParentTabRegion", Tab2);

        // Only the last registered view is displayed
        // _regionManger.RegisterViewWithRegion("ParentTabRegion", typeof(Tab1));
        // _regionManger.RegisterViewWithRegion("ParentTabRegion", typeof(Tab2));
    }
}
```

I also have the prism namespace in all the views:

```
xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
```

Maybe I'm not registering the `ParentTabRegion` somehow? But I don't have to register the other regions and they seem to just work out of the box.

Let me know if you know what I'm doing wrong or if there is something I'm missing. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested some other things out. Since I don't need dynamic tabs, I found this to be the cleanest solution using Prism:

Parent ViewModel:

```
public ParentViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
{
    _regionManager = regionManager;
    _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("ChildRegion", typeof(Child1View));
    _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("ChildRegion", typeof(Child2View));
}
```

Parent View:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="TabItem">
    <Setter Property="Header"
    Value="{Binding DataContext.Title}"/>
  </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TabControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ChildRegion" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just comment but can't due to low reputation. Anyway..

Check this post
[Prism 7 throws and exception when working with nested views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63641883/prism-7-throws-and-exception-when-working-with-nested-views/63810056#63810056)

As stated in the comments: "the problem is about how to inject scope region in ViewModel"
This video from Brian should help you with the issue.

https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/prism-mastering-tabcontrol

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out your answer on the other question. 

I've viewed the "Prism Mastering TabControl", but found that it really only covered the situation where all the child views were the same amongst all the tabs. I also find it hard to follow along with some of his video's(except the one that came out this year) since they use older versions of prism.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this a bit differently since I don't really need to dynamically add `Tabs`.

So what I ended up doing was just adding all the `ViewModels` to an `ObservableCollection` of `BindableBase`. Then I just added them to the view using a `DataTemplate`.

Parent ViewModel:

```
private ObservableCollection <BindableBase> _childTabs;

public ObservableCollection <BindableBase> ChildTabs
{
   get { return _childTabs; }
   set { _childTabs = value; }
}

public ParentViewModel() 
{    
    ChildTabs = new ObservableCollection <BindableBase> {
      new Child1ViewModel(),
      new Child2ViewModel()
    };
}
```

Parent View:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding ChildTabs}"
                SelectedIndex="0">
  <TabControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Child1ViewModel}">
      <view:Child1 />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Child2ViewModel}">
      <view:Child2 />
    </DataTemplate>
    </DataTemplate>
  </TabControl.Resources>
  <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

I still feel like I'm doing something wrong though, this doesn't feel like `MVVM` to me...